# Tasker Action Plugin variable replacement

Tags: android, plugins, tasker

There are many questions on this but I could not find an example matching my situation.
I am trying to add a Tasker plugin to my app. It works but the variable values are not passed. Instead, only variable name is passed like %BATT.

I read here:
http://tasker.dinglisch.net/plugins.html

it says that I have to add following lines to my EditActivity:

```
  if ( TaskerPlugin.Setting.hostSupportsOnFireVariableReplacement( this ) )
                TaskerPlugin.Setting.setVariableReplaceKeys( resultBundle, new String [] { "com.saple.plugin.MYVALUE" } );
```

but I could not find where to put these lines.
Below is my editactivity class:

```
package com.test.app;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.aktuna.gear.defilmirz.R;
import com.aktuna.gear.defilmirz.bundle.BundleScrubber;
import com.aktuna.gear.defilmirz.bundle.PluginBundleManager;

//import com.twofortyfouram.locale.Intent;

/**
 * This is the "Edit" activity for a Locale Plug-in.
 * <p>
 * This Activity can be started in one of two states:
 * <ul>
 * <li>New plug-in instance: The Activity's Intent will not contain
 * {@link com.twofortyfouram.locale.Intent#EXTRA_BUNDLE}.</li>
 * <li>Old plug-in instance: The Activity's Intent will contain
 * {@link com.twofortyfouram.locale.Intent#EXTRA_BUNDLE} from a previously saved plug-in instance that the
 * user is editing.</li>
 * </ul>
 *
 * @see com.twofortyfouram.locale.Intent#ACTION_EDIT_SETTING
 * @see com.twofortyfouram.locale.Intent#EXTRA_BUNDLE
 */
public final class EditActivity extends AbstractPluginActivity
{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        BundleScrubber.scrub(getIntent());

        final Bundle localeBundle = getIntent().getBundleExtra(com.twofortyfouram.locale.Intent.EXTRA_BUNDLE);
        BundleScrubber.scrub(localeBundle);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        if (null == savedInstanceState)
        {
            if (PluginBundleManager.isBundleValid(localeBundle))
            {
                final String message =
                        localeBundle.getString(PluginBundleManager.BUNDLE_EXTRA_STRING_MESSAGE);
                ((EditText) findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText(message);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void finish()
    {
        if (!isCanceled())
        {
            final String message = ((EditText) findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).getText().toString();

            if (message.length() > 0)
            {
                final Intent resultIntent = new Intent();

                /*
                 * This extra is the data to ourselves: either for the Activity or the BroadcastReceiver. Note
                 * that anything placed in this Bundle must be available to Locale's class loader. So storing
                 * String, int, and other standard objects will work just fine. Parcelable objects are not
                 * acceptable, unless they also implement Serializable. Serializable objects must be standard
                 * Android platform objects (A Serializable class private to this plug-in's APK cannot be
                 * stored in the Bundle, as Locale's classloader will not recognize it).
                 */
                final Bundle resultBundle =
                        PluginBundleManager.generateBundle(getApplicationContext(), message);
              resultIntent.putExtra(com.twofortyfouram.locale.Intent.EXTRA_BUNDLE, resultBundle);

                /*
                 * The blurb is concise status text to be displayed in the host's UI.
                 */
                final String blurb = generateBlurb(getApplicationContext(), message);
                resultIntent.putExtra(com.twofortyfouram.locale.Intent.EXTRA_STRING_BLURB, blurb);

                setResult(RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
            }
        }

        super.finish();
    }

    /**
     * @param context Application context.
     * @param message The toast message to be displayed by the plug-in. Cannot be null.
     * @return A blurb for the plug-in.
     */
    /* package */static String generateBlurb(final Context context, final String message)
    {
        final int maxBlurbLength =
                context.getResources().getInteger(R.integer.twofortyfouram_locale_maximum_blurb_length);

        if (message.length() > maxBlurbLength)
        {
            return message.substring(0, maxBlurbLength);
        }

        return message;
    }
}
```

I'd appreciate if someone can tell me what to do...

Answer (score 0):

I found it.
The generateBundle function was under PluginBundleManager.generateBundle
and all I had to do was to add:
        result.putString("net.dinglisch.android.tasker.extras.VARIABLE_REPLACE_KEYS",BUNDLE_EXTRA_STRING_MESSAGE);